# Displaying an <a> anchor inline

Tags: html, css

What CSS makes `<a>` tags show on a single line, rather than under each other? 
Maybe have a link in `<li>` tag?

Comment: checkout the css display:block property. It will help you show the tags in next lines

Comment: Please make your question more clear by adding your CSS

Comment: I'm a bit confused. do you want the links to be displayed one below the next (like a to-do list) or one right after the next (like a in-sentence-form list)? Can you please show mus what you have so far and further clarify what you need?

Comment: Solved i did need this `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @user2736147 if one of the solutions helped get your answer, please mark it as correct for future users to quickly reference (click the check mark icon to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

**edit**

Anchors by default show inline, but the related CSS is:

```
a {
    display: inline;
}
```

You could also use `inline-block` which gives you a bit more functionality (although some older browsers support it poorly).

Comment: @user2736147 I've updated my answer to show how to display them inline.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a link in a `<li>` tag:

```
<ul>

<li> 
<a href="#">Link here.</a> 
</li>

</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/asRz3/)

Comment: Thank you it was this i needed display:inline-block;

Answer (score 4):

I created an example for you which answers your second question.

```
<p id="top">This is the top of the file</p>

<ul> Favourite sports
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football">Football</a></li>
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis">Tennis</a></li>
<li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_football">Rugby</a></li>
</ul>



<p><a href="#top">This link goes to the top</a></p>
```

The tag li refers to list item. Links are written the same way in ordered and unordered lists.

Comment: Do you mean a link next to each other?